# How to get the current logged User in a service

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8

In Symfony 2.8/3.0, with our fancy new security components, how do I get the currently logged `User` (*i.e. FOSUser*) object in a service **without** injecting the whole container?

Is it even possible in a *non-hacky way*?

PS: Let's not consider the "*pass it to the service function as a parameter*" for being trivially obvious. Also, dirty.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Inject `security.token_storage` service into your service, and then use:

```
$this->token_storage->getToken()->getUser();
```

as described here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#retrieving-the-user-object and here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#referencing-injecting-services

Comment: I did this, but when I request the token, I get `null`. Is there something I missed to set?

Comment: "**Always Check if the User is Logged In**
It's important to check if the user is authenticated first. If they're not, $user will either be null or the string anon.. Wait, what? Yes, this is a quirk. If you're not logged in, the user is technically the string anon., though the getUser() controller shortcut converts this to null for convenience." https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security.html#always-check-if-the-user-is-logged-in

Answer (score 67):

**Works with Symfony 3.4, 4.x, 5.x & above. The Security utility class was introduced in Symfony 3.4.**

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

public function indexAction(Security $security)
{
    $user = $security->getUser();
}
```

https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/security.html#always-check-if-the-user-is-logged-in

Comment: Works for Symfony 4

Comment: I don't fully understand why `Security` is recommended over `TokenStorageInterface` and/or `AuthorizationCheckerInterface` as the class is `final` which makes it impossible to mock which in turn makes unit testing services dependent on these services harder than it needs to be.

Comment: I guess you should never change your code just because of how easy you can write (phpunit) tests for it. Having and using final classes makes much sense. You can mock final classes for example using hooks: https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2019/03/28/how-to-mock-final-classes-in-phpunit/

Comment: @Liiva From what I can tell from here it's because the user may not be logged in yet when the service constructor runs.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-fetching-the-user-from-a-service

Comment: @Liiva: I've checked Security class source (https://github.com/symfony/security-core/blob/5.2/Security.php) and it only has `@final` in doc and is not marked `final`. Mocking works fine, tested with Symfony 5.2.9.

Comment: @k00ni You're correct but at the time of writing it was a final class and later moved to the docs as part of this commit: https://github.com/symfony/security-core/commit/a44d4cef38ce2c9b8e43d94e4847ebcb5f0e65ef#diff-9883341373efe75f508748760a2f2b8f2ab98e90db5b49dc6b7063c83ff32406

Comment: Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security is depredated since 6.2 use use Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Security instead

Answer (score 47):

Using constructor dependency injection, you can do it this way:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class A
{
    private $user;

    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->user = $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
    }

    public function foo()
    {
        dump($this->user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you say it's only for Symfony 3.3+ ? What part of your code doesn't work in older versions of Symfony?

Comment: For some reason, I thought constructor dependency injection wasn't supported earlier, but that's not true. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: When I call `$tokenStorage->getToken()` I receive `null`. What could be the reason for this? The user is logged in ...

Comment: If you get `$tokenStorage->getToken()` equal `null`, try storing the whole `$tokenStorage` as a class property, i.e. in `__construct(...)`: `$this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage`.

Comment: Related to the comment of @iloo: It is important **when** you use the token storage. As stated [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#b-fetching-the-user-from-a-service), the `auth` process might not be complete, when the service-constructor gets called. Therefore store the reference `$tokenStorage->getToken()` or use `Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security` instead. Can't tell the difference in behavior between those 2. `Security` seems to be common in Symfony 4+.

Comment: +1 for putting the NS import, often overlooked but there are several and it's a pain figuring out which one goes with the answer!

Answer (score 24):

In symfo 4 :

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;

class ExampleService
{
    private $security;

    public function __construct(Security $security)
    {
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    public function someMethod()
    {
        $user = $this->security->getUser();
    }
}
```

See doc : https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#retrieving-the-user-object

Comment: Good answer, works for me on Symfony 6

Answer (score 5):

From `Symfony 3.3`, **from a Controller only**, according this blog post: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-2-user-value-resolver-for-controllers

It's easy as:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface

public function indexAction(UserInterface $user)
{...}
```

Answer (score 3):

With Symfony 5.2+ and PHP 8.0+ you can also get the logged user using the `#[CurrentUser]` attribute

```php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Attribute\CurrentUser;

class FooController extends AbstractController
{
    public function index(#[CurrentUser] ?User $user)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

- Blog post: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-2-controller-argument-attributes
- Documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html

Comment: This is the best practice now. Note that if your controller is secured with the `IsGranted` attribute, you can make the user type not nullable `#[CurrentUser] User $user`.

Answer (score 2):

Symfony does this in Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\ControllerControllerTrait

```
protected function getUser()
{
    if (!$this->container->has('security.token_storage')) {
        throw new \LogicException('The SecurityBundle is not registered in your application.');
    }

    if (null === $token = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()) {
        return;
    }

    if (!is_object($user = $token->getUser())) {
        // e.g. anonymous authentication
        return;
    }

    return $user;
}
```

So if you simply inject and replace `security.token_storage`, you're good to go.

Comment: replace  security.token_storage by what?

Comment: I'd recommend this answer now https://stackoverflow.com/a/46413924/519333

Answer (score 0):

if you class extend of Controller

```
$this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

Or, if you has access to container element..

```
$container = $this->configurationPool->getContainer();
$user = $container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-security-component-improvements

Comment: The class is a service, not a controller (technically, it *can* be both, but it's rare and ugly). Also, I explicitly asked to not inject the controller. Thus, your answer, though *kinda* correct, violates both pre-conditions so it's technically invalid. Thanks, though.