# How to get the currently logged in user in a service with symfony 3.4

Tags: php, authentication, symfony-3.4

Using symfony 3.4, I have a service for custom Exception handling:

```
class CustomExceptionController extends ExceptionController
{
    [...]
}
```

Now I want to log the exception and with it the currently logged in user. Since I am not extending from a standard `Controller` I can't do the following:

```
$user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
```

So I found this question on Stackoverflow: [How to get the current logged User in a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36870272/how-to-get-the-current-logged-user-in-a-service) but for some reason when I inject `TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage`into the constructor, I get `null` when I call `$tokenStorage->getToken()`.

What can be the reason for that? My services.yml looks as follows:

```
AppBundle\Controller\CustomExceptionController:
    public: true
    arguments: ["@twig", %kernel.debug%, "@doctrine.orm.log_entity_manager", '@security.token_storage']
```

and my controller like this:

```
public function __construct(Environment $twig, bool $debug, EntityManager $entityManager, TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
{
    $this->em = $entityManager;
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    parent::__construct($twig, $debug);
}
```

Did I miss something? I double-checked and the user is logged in. But I always get `null` when requesting the token.

Comment: My best guess would be that the token storage is filled **later** by a firewall (it's easy to confirm it with a debugger). Have you tried to call `$tokenStorage->getToken()` not in constructor but action instead?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the bug, it does just work for me... can you please give us infos about **how** you do call this controller ? is this in twig's config that you've set it as `exception_controller` or do you call it manually ?