# getting current logged in user - symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

```
public function agencyHome(EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    $repository = $em->getRepository(Ships::class);
    // $ships = $repository->findByOwner($own);
    $ships = $repository->findAll();
    return $this->render('agency/index.html.twig', [
        'ships' => $ships,
    ]);
}
```

on the code above i need to pass current logged in user to a repository, so i can find all related "ships"
i tried with $u = $this->getUser()->getId(); with no succes :(

thank you in advance :)

Comment: In what context are you trying to get the current user - is this on the controller layer or the service layer?

Comment: in this controller which extends AbstractController

Comment: In general. when using the Doctrine ORM you will never access or use the id.  Might need to review the basics.

Comment: let's say i want to post a comment by current authenticated user :). how ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the current logged User in a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36870272/how-to-get-the-current-logged-user-in-a-service)

Answer (score 5):

In a Symfony 4 controller, you should be able to access the user using `$this->getUser()` within a controller providing that the user is authorized. If there is no logged in user, it should return `null`.

```
public function agencyHome(EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_USER');
    $user = $this->getUser();
}
```

Alternatively, you should also be able to inject the `UserInterface` class into the method parameters through which you can get information about the current logged in user.

```
public function agencyHome(EntityManagerInterface $em, UserInterface $user)
{
   ...
}
```

I've tested these on a Symfony 4 application, though I can't remember if I had to do anything else in the configuration so please let me know if you have any issues with them.

Referenced from https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html

Comment: i know that very well, however, how do i get the ID of the user so i can pass it to a repository, to select some items related to the current user

Comment: So from my test on my application, I was able to call `$this->getUser()->getId()` as per your original attempt and it returned me with the user ID. Alternatively, with using the `UserInterface` injection, I had to get the username with `$user->getUsername()` and then perform a look up on the `UserRepository` myself. Are either of these options working for you? Is the user actually being logged in?

Comment: I couldn't inject `UserInterface` but was able to do so with `TokenStorageInterface`. Calling `$this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser()` retrieves the currently logged in user.