# How to get the currently logged in User in EasyAdmin

Tags: symfony, doctrine, easyadmin

How can I fetch the currently logged in User from anywhere within the Backend code? For example I have an EventSubscriber class and want to fetch it from there.

How can I do that w/o the help of i.e. AbstractController?

Comment: Temporariliy solved it by extending `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController`. (Probably bad practice)

Comment: Check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36870272/how-to-get-the-current-logged-user-in-a-service#answer-52465117) is working for you.

Answer (score 3):

Symfony [AbstractController](https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/5.4/Controller/AbstractController.php) is the core of most Controllers. Including EasyAdmin crud controller (XXXCrudController) extends AbstractController so you can access the same methods.

One of those is getUser() which return the current logged in user.

```
 * Get a user from the Security Token Storage.
 *
 * @return UserInterface|null
 *
 * @throws \LogicException If SecurityBundle is not available
 *
 * @see TokenInterface::getUser()
 */
protected function getUser()
{
    if (!$this->container->has('security.token_storage')) {
        throw new \LogicException('The SecurityBundle is not registered in your application. Try running "composer require symfony/security-bundle".');
    }

    if (null === $token = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()) {
        return null;
    }

    // @deprecated since 5.4, $user will always be a UserInterface instance
    if (!\is_object($user = $token->getUser())) {
        // e.g. anonymous authentication
        return null;
    }

    return $user;
}
```

So when trying to get the logged used in a controller, just use this method.

If you want to get the same thing, but for example in a service, you can basically do the same as what the method actually does by using the service injection with TokenStorageInterface to access the [TokenStorage](https://github.com/symfony/security-core/blob/5.4/Authentication/Token/Storage/TokenStorage.php) service which can get the current user.

So in your event subscriber, add TokenStorageInterface in your constructor to use it to first get the token and then your user. You may have to add another check to see if there is an user logged in (by checking if there is a token for example)

```
//YourService.php
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

private $tokenStorage
public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
{
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
}

public function yourMethod()
{
    //get token then user
    $user = $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
}
```